# How to get filename when using Launch Services

Tags: cocoa, launch-services

I register my app with:

```
NSString *self_id=[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];

CFStringRef cfString;

cfString = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(
                                                 kUTTagClassFilenameExtension,
                                                 CFSTR("fdp"),
                                                 kUTTypeData);

OSStatus a = LSSetDefaultRoleHandlerForContentType((CFStringRef)cfString,kLSRolesViewer,(CFStringRef)self_id);
```

But on the other side, how can i get the filename the finder send to my app?
what the mechanism should i set for getting the filename?
Is there any document about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If your application is document-based, the document controller will create a document object for each opened file automatically. You don't need to do anything at run time to handle the files; just implement your document class and declare the right things in your Info.plist, as described in [Document-Based Applications Overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Documents/).

If your application is not document-based, you need to create an object to be the delegate of the application object. In that object, respond to [the `application:openFiles:` message](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSApplicationDelegate/application%3aopenFiles%3a).